# Is there a way to put up different expiry times for different elements I insert in ignitecache?

Tags: java, caching, guava, ehcache, ignite

Can I insert elements having different expiry times like we have in ehcache

For example :

Cache : add element1 //expire after 5 seconds

cache : add element2 //expire after 15 seconds

cache : add element3 //expire after 'x' seconds/minutes

If not, can you suggest any alternative cache to deal with the problem ?

I intended to use ehcache as well but turns out it doesn't support active/eager expiry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cache entries have individual expiry policies, use `IgniteCache.withExpiryPolicy`:

```java
cache.withExpiryPolicy(new CreatedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(SECONDS, 5))).put(1, 1);

cache.withExpiryPolicy(new CreatedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(SECONDS, 15))).put(2, 2);
```